# Laravel take about 10s before rendering a simple view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on an existing project built with laravel 5.4 and after I run it in my local machine I realized that all the requests are very slow, so in order to see what slowing down the pages I created a new route:

```
Route::get('/some/route','TestController@index');
```

TestController:

```
class DashboardAutoEvalController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        echo "Access controller action at: " . time() . "\n"; 
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }

}
```

index.blade.php

```
<h1>Access view at {{ time() }}</h1>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see the view take about 9s after it compiles and renders

Comment: Do you have any view composer that does things for 9 seconds? https://blackfire.io/ can probably tell you where that time is going.

Comment: @sisve you are right, I found many view composer that slowing down the pages